# How i can get the privacy setting of a just uploaded picture?

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api

In my app i have this code to share in my facebook wall a picture:

```
-(void)PictureShare{
    NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Appname",  @"message", nil];
    [params setObject:MyPicture forKey:@"source"];

    [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me/photos"
                                 parameters:params
                                 HTTPMethod:@"POST"
                          completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                              id result,
                                              NSError *error)
     {
         if (error)
         {
             //showing an alert for failure
         }
         else
         {
             //showing an alert for success
         }
     }];
}
```

This method works correctly but i want to know the privacy settings of the picture that i have just uploaded, it is shared in "Public","Only friends" or maybe "Only me"?. How i can do? the result dictionary returns only post_it and photo_id.

Comment: that is perfectly enough privacy information, which you'd need to see about the client's Facebook account settings – nothing else is the developer's business in that scenario, and the Facebook won't tell you.

Comment: so there's no way? if you wanna insert as answer i'll mark it as correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set the privacy using the `privacy` parameter. From the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/photos):

> Determines the privacy settings of the photo. If not supplied, this defaults to the privacy level granted to the app in the Login Dialog. This field cannot be used to set a more open privacy setting than the one granted.